# Is there a way to declare local variables in Lisp (avoiding let)?

Tags: lisp, let

I'm fond of Lisp, but one of the thing I find irksome about it is that it nests too much.

In an imperative programming language, I can break a long expression by using an intermediate value, for instance:

```c
int x = someFunctionCall() ? someOtherFunctionCall() : 42;
int y = myUnterminableNameFunction(x);
```

instead of

```c
int x = myUnterminableNameFunction(someFunctionCall() ? someOtherFunctionCall() : 42);
```

This can be done in Lisp too, but as far as I'm aware, only by using `let`. `let` introduces an additional level of nesting, which I'd rather avoid.

I'm not looking to argue that opinion, but to find a way to declare local variable in a single, non-nesting function/macro call. Something like `declare_local` in the following:

```
(defun my_function (a b)
   (declare_local x (if (some_function_call) (some_other_function_call) 42))
   (my_unterminable_name_function x))
```

If it does not exist, can it maybe be implemented via a clever macro, without it being detrimental to performances?

Comment: I find it odd that you're fond of lisp but not fond of parenthesis nesting!  It's kind of the nature of the beast, isn't it?

Comment: What I love about Lisp are macros, mostly. The parentheses make macro easier and are tolerated for this reason :) Still I'm looking for ways to keep my parentheses sparse.

Comment: I'm not clear about the advantage of `declare_local` for you.  Is it just that there's one less parenthesis at the end of the function?

Comment: Basically, it avoids a bunch of nested `let` inside functions. As such, it saves on indentation, and yes, on those confusing closing parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a proof of concept macro that pulls variable declarations from a flat list up into standard `let*` forms.

```
(defun my/vardecl-p (x)
  "Return true if X is a (VAR NAME VALUE) form."
  (and (listp x)
       (> (length x) 1)
       (eq 'var (car x))))

(defmacro my/defun (name args &rest body)
  "Special form of DEFUN with a flatter format for LET vars"
  (let ((vardecls (mapcar #'cdr
                          (remove-if-not #'my/vardecl-p body)))
        (realbody (remove-if #'my/vardecl-p body)))
    `(defun ,name ,args
       (let* ,vardecls
         ,@realbody))))
```

Example:

```
(my/defun foo (a b)
  (var x 2)
  (var y 3)
  (* x y a b))

(foo 4 5)
; => 120
```

Comment: Currently the best solution I see. To be complete it should handle nested lists and replace declarations by `setf` calls. Like I said elsewhere, it has the disadvantage that it does not apply to macros that expand to `defun` or `lambda`.

Comment: I can't say that I particularly like this workaround for the way lisp is supposed to work, but +1 for actually answering the question. Who knows? this might come in handy some day.

Answer (score 8):

You may use `let*` form for sequential binding.

```
(let* ((x (if (some-function-call)
             (some-other-call)
             42))
       (y (my-unterminable-name-function x)))
   (bla-bla-bla)
   ...)
```

It does nest, but not so much.

As of `declare-local`, it has to be processed by some outer macro.  For example, you may write `my-defun` that checks for `declare-local` in its body and transforms it.  **Upd** but it is somewhat anti-Lisp.  Lisp forms usually affect only nested forms.  `cl:declare` is the only exception I can think of.

Comment: I am aware of `let*`, but as you say, it's not quite what I was searching. I have also considered to define macro alternatives to `defun` and `lambda` that would search for occurrences of `declare_local`, replace them by calls to `setf`, and wrap the whole body in a `let*`. It is the best solution I could come up with, although it has the significant pitfall that you can't use `declare_local` inside macros that expand to the vanilla `defun` or `lambda`.

Comment: Thus, `declare-local` has more drawbacks than `let*, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Well, it seems the best thing to do for me would be to use `declare_local` when possible and `let` and `let*` otherwise. But the whole point of the question was to find a foolproof way to define `declare_local`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in Common Lisp use `&aux` arguments:

```
(defun foo (a b &aux x y z)
  (setq x ...)
  (setq y ...)
  .... )
```

Or use the ["`prog` feature"](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_prog_.htm):

```
(defun bar (a b)
  (prog (x y)
    (setq x a y b) 
    ....
    (return 42)
    ))
```

Comment: But it means I have to declare all variables ahead of time, like it was done in C in the days of yore.

Also what you propose is basically equivalent to `(let (x y) ...)` (I don't really need `return` and `go` as offered by `prog`).

Comment: @Norswap that's what you wanted, no? -- ok, so prog didn't really add much, it was just "not let". -- you can also use let with only some vars declared in advance, for closer-to-use-site declarations and smaller total number of lets overall (than in fully "nested" coding style). Or you eliminate lets completely with all the declarations done in advance. Find the balance that works for you. :)

Comment: @Norswap if you want your declarations local, just not nested, then it must be a macro, say `def`, which would recognize, say, `(deflocal ...)` forms and re-group things into nested lets.

Comment: Possibly there is no need to `setq` the `&aux` locals. Try this: `(funcall (lambda (x &aux (y x)) (list x y)) 1)`.

Comment: @Kaz perhaps but if the expressions are large and unwieldy then code with setq's might be easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

No, there are no forms which can occur in a `progn`-like body and suddenly declare new variables which have a scope over the remainder of the `progn`.

While this would be convenient in some ways (such as less indentation and fewer whitespace-only diffs in version control), there is a big down-side: it is a lot harder to write code which analyzes code.

Lisp is structured so that when we look at the leftmost symbol of a compound form, we know what it is, and there is some rigid, easy to parse syntax next to that symbol which tells us what symbols, if any, are introduced over the scope of that construct. (If it does such a thing, it is called a *binding construct*).

A binding construct that can have variable definitions scattered throughout the body requires extra work to find all these places.

If you really miss this feature from other languages, you can write yourself a macro which will implement it for you.

Here is a possible start.

Let us call the macro `(begin ...)`, and inside `(begin ...)` let us support syntax of the form `(new (var [initform])*)` which introduces one or more variables using `let` syntax, except that it has no body. The scope of these variables is the remainder of the `begin` form.

The task, then, is to make the macro transform syntax of this form:

```
(begin
  a b c
  (new (x 42))
  d e
  (new (y 'foo) (z))
  f g)
```

into, say, this code:

```
(progn
  a b c
  (let ((x 42))
    d e
    (let ((y 'foo) (z))
      f g)))
```

The `begin` macro has to look at all of its argument forms, and tell apart the `(new ...)` ones from anything else, and generate the nested `let` structure.

> The above transformation problem has a structure which suggests a straightforward recursive solution.

A modern industrial-strength `begin` will have to provide for declarations. Perhaps we can allow a `(new ...)` form to be immediately followed by a `(declare ...)` form. The two are then folded according to the pattern `((new A ...) (declare B ...) C ...)` **->** `(let (A ...) (declare B ...) C ...)`, where we recursively process `(C ...)` for more occurrences of `(new ...)`.

Of course, if you have this `begin` macro, you have to explicitly use it. There isn't any easy way to retarget existing Lisp constructs which have an "implicit progn" such that they have an "implicit begin".

Of course, what you can always do is implement a very complicated macro which looks like this:

```
(my-dialect-of-lisp
  ;; file full of code in your customized dialect of Lisp goes here
  )
```

The `my-dialect-of-lisp` macro parses the dialect (i.e. implements a full code walker for that dialect) and spits out a translation into standard Lisp.

---

#### Appendix: Implementation of `(begin ...)`

(Without declaration support):

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (defun begin-expander (forms)
    (if (null forms)
      nil
      (destructuring-bind (first &rest rest) forms
        (if (and (consp first)
                 (eq (first first) 'new))
          `((let (,@(rest first)) ,@(begin-expander rest)))
          `(,first ,@(begin-expander rest)))))))

(defmacro begin (&rest forms)
  (let ((expansion (begin-expander forms)))
    (cond
      ;; (begin) -> nil
      ((null expansion) nil)
      ;; (begin (new ...) ...) -> ((let (...) ...)) -> (let (...) ...)
      ((and (consp (first expansion))
            (eq (first (first expansion)) 'let))
        (first expansion))
      ;; (begin ...) -> (...) -> (progn ...)
      (t `(progn ,@expansion)))))
```

This kind of a thing is better expressed with the help of a pattern matching library.